# Why Adsense ads don't show up in website home page

Tags: adsense, ads

I have a News website. Adsense ads are showing on internal pages. but ads are not showing on website home page.

I've done Adsense troubleshooter suggestions. and It seems everything is ok...

Website address is : http://akhbaralalam.com

Maybe useful : When I put a random argument like "/?123" to the end of URL, ads are showing.

akhbaralalam.com    -> ads don't show up

akhbaralalam.com/?123 -> ads show up

Is there any suggestions or something?

Can you please investigate the page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the way I realized what the problem is...

I had a funny mistake: On pages with more than 3 Ad units it may result to disappearing all the ads.

also I added privacy policy to the footer of the site. In google adsense guids they said it's necessary to have a privacy policy including some certain topics like cookies...

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem with this also just a week ago, some sites says its about the privacy policy to be updated. But it didn't work for me. I found the way to fixed it in just a few clicks on settings. I tried it on blogger platform but once you see it you'll know how in Wordpress and other CMS.

> Go to Blogger settings ->> Search Preferences ->> Enable search description.
>   Click yes then put your sites description and save.

source link: http://www.blogs911.com/2014/06/fixed-adsense-ads-not-showing-in-homepage-of-blogs-and-websites.html

Comment: please provide a full answer, not just a link